# can you override in solidity

Tags: solidity

in this code  what is part 1 part 2 part 3 part 4

```
   contract MyContract {
  // part 1
  uint count;
  uint[] totalPoints;

  function localVars(){
     // part 2
     uint[] localArr;
     // part 3
     uint[] memory memoryArr;
     // part 4
     uint[] pointer = totalPoints;
  }
}
```

can i do this

```
function doSomething(uint[] storage args) internal returns(uint[] storage data) {…}
```

Comment: first part is answered secod part can you describe what do you want to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1 — Storage.

Part 2 — Storage (array size points to the same location as `counter`)

Part 3 — Memory.

Part 4 — Reference to Storage.

Comment: Part 2 is a syntax error in recent version of solc (data location is missing).